# Bash script executing curl json query piped to python inline script for parsing json, proper execution

Tags: python, json, bash, curl, pipe

The long form of this command works but is not as readable as I would like:

```
curl -X GET http://somewhere.ext/json | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['key']['valueIWant']
```

The result of that query is just a single value contained in key.valueIWant.

To try and make it more readable, I tried to do this but can't come up with the right syntax or there is something I'm missing fundamentally:

```
CURLCMD="curl -X GET http://somewhere.ext/json"
PYTHONCMD=$"python -c \"import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['key']['valueIWant']\""
$VALUE=$( $CURLCMD | $PYTHONCMD )
```

echo $CURLCMD yields:

```
curl -X GET http://somewhere.ext/json
```

This is correct.

echo $PYTHONCMD yields:

```
python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['key']['valueIWant']"
```

This is correct.

When I copy the output of those echos and pipe them together, the command works.  When I try to find the short form expanding the variables, none of the variations I can think of works.

Most of the variations of $CURLCMD | $PYTHONCMD complain about an EOL character after the import.  I think the curl output has a EOL with no new line character at the end of it, so maybe that is giving it a problem.   I don't understand why the long version with the pipe works, but the expanded variable version doesn't.

Just a few of the other variations I've tried:

```
VALUE=$( $CURLCMD | $PYTHONCMD )
VALUE=$( CURLCMD ) | ( $PYTHONCMD )
VALUE=$( ${CURLCMD} | ${PYTHONCMD} )
```

(really I thought the last one was the closest to the long form, but I guess not.)

Is there a form of $CURLCMD | $PYTHONCMD that will work like how the long form works?

This works and is better readable, but seems like there ought to be a way to use variable expansion to do the same thing.

```
VALUE=$( $CURLCMD | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['key']['valueIWant']")
```

(This is from memory as I'm not anywhere near the script right now.)

Comment: I have found that this works and is readable enough for my purposes:

`VALUE=$( $CURLCMD |  python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['key']['valueIWant']" - )`

(It works / reading the stdin with or without the trailing - )
On the other hand, if there is a better way to get these commands to work together in a shorter form or if there is a key thing I'm missing I would like to learn.

Comment: I don't know if it's *the* problem, but *a* problem is using `$VALUE` on the left-hand side of the assignment. It should just be `VALUE=$(...`; making that change on a simpler test-case here works just fine (`value=$( $v1 | $v2)`)

Comment: Sorry that is just a typo.  I can't copy and paste my actual code from where it lives so I have to try and explain it from scratch.